# Determine the amount of clicks required to reach a specific date using a JQuery calendar?

Tags: ruby, watir

I have a jquery calendar for the start date of a project.

Using Watir (automated browser driver, a gem for ruby), I have a set date that I would like to enter in.

The calendar start date is always today's date, whatever that may be for the day it is used.  I was wondering if there was a way that ruby can process what today's date is, and use the specified date provided by the user, to calculate the difference of months between them.

Here is an example of the Calendar plugin: http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

example:

today's date is 30/10/2012, if there was a project that were to start on the 20/12/2012, that would be 2 months from now, so 2 clicks on the next month button.

Is there a way I could do this?

Comment: Are you testing the calender? If not, you would probably be better off just setting the text field directly.

Comment: Agree - I only interact with the calendar when the text_field attached to it is readOnly.  If you're not testing the calendar itself you just need to set the date in the simplest way to move forward.

Comment: @JustinKo, the tests are supposed to simulate an actual user using the application, so yes the test would be for the calendar.  I did indeed consider a direct input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do:

```
#End date converted to date object
specified_date = '20/12/2012'
end_date = Date.parse(specified_date)

#Start date (today - 30/10/2012)
today  = Date.today

#Determine difference in months
number_of_months_up_to_today = (today.month + today.year * 12)
number_of_months_up_to_end = (end_date.month + end_date.year * 12)
clicks_required = number_of_months_up_to_end - number_of_months_up_to_today
#=> 2
```

Basically it is counting the number of months since the year 0 and then finding the difference.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I approached a similar situation with JSdatepicker:

```
$today = Time.now.strftime("%e").gsub(" ", "") #one digit day of month without leading space

@browser.text_field(:id => /dateAvailable/).click
Watir::Wait.until(60) {@browser.div(:id => /dateAvailable_popup_cal/).td(:text => $today).exists?}
@browser.div(:id => /dateAvailable_popup_cal/).td(:text => $today).click
```

1. Set or grab the date.
2. Click the text_field that fires the JSDatePicker object
3. Wait until the calendar actually pops up
4. The current month is shown, so choose today's date number.

In your case, you also need to set the month.  Whether prompting the user for this, or choosing "today", the theory is the same:

```
$month = Date::MONTHNAMES[Date.today.month] #etc
```

Pseudo-code making lots of assumptions (only future dates, month name shown on calendar as text, etc):

```
while !@jquerytablewindow.text.include?($month)
     next_month_button.click
end
```

I don't see a specific advantage to my method versus counting each month, unless of course we add a month to the calendar one day and you still want your code to work!